# Jquery Datatables responsive not working properly

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I'm using data tables with responsive plugin,

```
https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/css/responsive.dataTables.css
https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/js/dataTables.responsive.js
```

Here is my screen result:

**Desktop view:**
[image: view on desktop mode]

**Mobile view top:**

[image: mobile view 1]

**Mobile view bottom:**

[image: mobile view 2]

**My JS code:**

```
    dataTable = $('#agency_data').DataTable({
    "processing":true,
    "serverSide":true,
    "order":[],
    responsive: true,

    "language": {
    "infoFiltered": ""
    },
    "ajax":{
        url:base_url+"/agency-listing",
        type:"POST"
    },
    "columnDefs":[
        {
            "targets":[0, 3], //first and last not sortable
            "orderable":false,
        },          
    ],

});
```

**My table's HTML:**

```
        <table id="agency_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr class="info">
        <th width="10%">ID</th>
        <th width="15%">Agency Code</th>
        <th width="65%">Agency Name</th>
        <th width="15%">Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        </table>
```

**JSFIDDLE:** [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/91Lwpt6r/)

**Question:**

1) On mobile view, how to get the Long organization name, showing perfectly? like BR?

2) How to get rid the horizontal scroll on the bottom, so that user no need to scroll on mobile view?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

added : width="100%" into table solved the problem

```
<table id="agency_data" class="table table-bordered table-striped" width="100%">
```

Comment: If it is solved your problem, then please [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)